# Performance Counters - Performance Category creation error

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I am getting an error when I try to create a new Performance Category from my ASP.NET application. Initially I had some registry related issues but they were solved by giving the user some permissions over some registry keys and adding it to the "Performance Log Users" and "Performance Monitor Users" groups. But now I am getting an exception and I don't know what else to try.

The error happens when I execute this line:

```
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(testName, testDescription, PerformanceCounterCategoryType.Unknown, counters);
```

`testName` and `testDescriptions` are string variables that contains name and description of the category and counters is a CounterCreationDataCollection
with 3 counters.

Here is the stack trace of the exception:

> at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.RegisterFiles(String
>   arg0, Boolean unregister)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterLib.RegisterCategory(String
>   categoryName, PerformanceCounterCategoryType categoryType, String
>   categoryHelp, CounterCreationDataCollection creationData)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(String
>   categoryName, String categoryHelp, PerformanceCounterCategoryType
>   categoryType, CounterCreationDataCollection counterData)    at
>   CL.Libraries.PerformanceTestUtils.InitializeCounters(List`1
>   usedCounters, String testName, String testDescription) in
>   C:\CL.Libraries\PerformanceTestUtils.cs:line 104

It seems I cannot post an image so here's what I get:

> " UnauthorizedAccessException was caught:
>
> Cannot create or delete the Performance Category 'C:\TEMP\tmpD5E8.tmp'
>   because access is denied. "

The category key is created in the registry. The file referred above is created and then deleted. I gave the user explicit access to the Temp folder but that didn't help either.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

> Your code is is executing without administrative privileges  and have
>   attempted to read a performance counter.

You need administrative privileges

The above message is taken from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb32hxtc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

HatSoft is completely correct, you need administrator access to create performance counters - something that you usually only need to perform once in order to create the counters. Once those are created you can easily instantiate a performance counter by name and then use it.

We typically (after the development of an application) place this step of the process in the installation procedure - once set up the application can use the counters at will.

I have a project on GitHub that shows basic usage on performance counters, it should help you get started:
https://github.com/stemarie/Karell.PerfCounters
You will need to run VS as administrator (right-click, run as administrator) in order for the unit test to run properly.