# Application Performance Counter Causes Exception

Tags: windows-10, performancecounter, windows-10-desktop

We are having a weird problem with custom performance counters. On a colleagues machine I am getting an exception that a performance counter doesn't exist. Yet on other machines I do not have that problem. These are custom performance counters for our application.

In a .NET 4.7.2 application, does writing performance counters or even creating them require elevated privileges? Is there a work around for application that is in the field?

TIA,
Doug

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636064/performance-counters-performance-category-creation-error

Comment: @HansPassant
Thanks! I was concerned that using performance counters required higher privileges. Some of our customers are allowed very few privileges on their machines. Looks like we need to either create them on installation or just remove them altogether. Shame really as they can be very handy when trying to understand performance related field problems.